# Why does FFmpeg add a second subtitle to my files, even though I explicitly only added one?

Tags: ffmpeg, vlc-media-player, shell-script, subtitles

I have a bunch of MP4 files and subtitle files in a folder, each following the pattern of `episode[num].mp4` and `episode[num].ass`.

I wrote a small shell script to automate combining those into MKV files:

```
for i in *.mp4; do 
  name=`echo $i | cut -d'.' -f1`;
  mp4name="$name.mp4";
  subname="$name.ass";
  mkvname="$name.mkv";
  ffmpeg -i "$mp4name" -i "$subname" -map 0:v -map 0:a -map 1:s -metadata:s:a language=jpn -metadata:s:s:0 language=eng -c copy -y "$mkvname"
done

echo "Done";
```

Upon opening one of the resulting MKV files, VLC shows two subtitle tracks:

[image: VLC subtitle menu showing two subtitle tracks, one labeled "Track 1 - English" and one just labeled "Track 2"]

Who’s to blame here? FFmpeg, VLC, or my quick and dirty script? And how do I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### VLC and you are to blame but it depends on your final goal.

FFmpeg is not adding subtitles twice, but VLC is automatically detecting the `.ass` file in the directory and adding it to the list of available subtitles. VLC looks for assets—such as subtitle files—that have the exact same name as the video file and load them into the player window for playback purposes.

So if you are playing `GreatMovie.mkv` you have a `GreatMovie.ass` file in the directory and play it, VLC will display the subtitles embedded in the MKV file *as well as* that `GreatMovie.ass` that is sitting next to the MKV file in that directory.

Now I say it depends on your final goal. If your final goal is simply one combined MKV file that contains all assets, you need to delete that `.ass` file after it’s done. So I would modify your script—by adding a `rm -f "$subname";` right after the `ffmpeg` command—as such to do that:

```
for i in *.mp4; do 
  name=`echo $i | cut -d'.' -f1`;
  mp4name="$name.mp4";
  subname="$name.ass";
  mkvname="$name.mkv";
  ffmpeg -i "$mp4name" -i "$subname" -map 0:v -map 0:a -map 1:s -metadata:s:a language=jpn -metadata:s:s:0 language=eng -c copy -y "$mkvname"
  rm -f "$subname";
done

echo "Done";
```

Or perhaps create a `completed_subs/` directory and move the subtitles to that directory when done.

```
for i in *.mp4; do 
  name=`echo $i | cut -d'.' -f1`;
  mp4name="$name.mp4";
  subname="$name.ass";
  mkvname="$name.mkv";
  ffmpeg -i "$mp4name" -i "$subname" -map 0:v -map 0:a -map 1:s -metadata:s:a language=jpn -metadata:s:s:0 language=eng -c copy -y "$mkvname"
  mkdir -p "completed_sub";
  mv $subname "completed_sub/$subname";
done

echo "Done";
```

That way you remove the subtitles from the processing directory so viewing the MKV file will only show subtitle assets embedded in the MKV file and the standalone subtitle `.ass` files are now in `completed_sub/`. So you can not only see what was completed, but also still retain the standalone subtitle files if you somehow need them in the future.

Comment: Makes sense, no idea why I didn't think of that. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You're to blame.

Remove the existing `.ass` file from the video's directory.

VLC is showing both the embeded subtitle and the one in the video's directory.